# Auto highlighting using values from DB with php

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have five (sometimes 7,8 etc.) php generated small HTML tables on the same page, each having a different `<table id="">`.  and I have data on mysql table with unique IDs which is the same as the html table ids.

What I need is each html table matching values to be highlighted with the values of the mysql table row with the same table id.

So instead of using a checkbox with multiple selector values, I need it to be done automatically without clicking any checkbox. Normally with checkboxes, I use something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zt54jqtL/
Thanks!!

```
<div>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="2" class="selector" />2</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="7" class="selector" />7</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="7" class="selector" />7</label>

</form>
```

PHP code:

```
 <?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Mdata");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


function print_tableX ($conn, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8 FROM tableA";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table id='$id'>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . join('</td><td>', $row) . "</td></tr>\n" ;
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}  


$result = $conn->query("SELECT sID from tableB");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_tableX ($conn, $row['sID']);
}

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: Can we have the php part?

Comment: Charlie, I haven't tried anything. I have know idea how to do it.

Comment: @Tobia, I included the php code in the post now. thanks.

Comment: @Tobia, do you know how i can get this result? can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I have understood correctly the question. Moreover from your code I cannot understand which rows have to be highlighted.

Let's say that this is the html generated:

```
<table id="tab1">
    <tr data-dbval="3"><td>Value</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr data-dbval="5"><td>Value</td><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr data-dbval="8"><td>Value</td><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>

 <table id="tab2">
    <tr data-dbval="2"><td>Value</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr data-dbval="7"><td>Value</td><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr data-dbval="8"><td>Value</td><td>8</td></tr>
 </table>
```

and this a javascript object with row references to be highlighted:

```
<script>
    var defaultValue={"tab1":["3","8"],"tab2":["7"]}
</script>
```

This jquery code gets values to be highlighted per table and adds a "highlight" class to tr element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.each(defaultValue,function(k,v){
    var $tab=$("table#"+k);
    if($tab.length>0){
        $.each(v,function(k1,v1){
        $tab.find("tr[data-dbval='"+v1+"']").addClass("highlight");
      })
    }
  })

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moc5sq4w/

To generate JS object from PHP you can use this (this is ugly embedded php). The SQL is just for example, I did not understand your DB data structure:

```
<script>
var defaultValue=<?php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT sID from tableB");
$out=array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id=$row['sID'];
    $out[$id]=array();
    $sql = "SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5 FROM tableA WHERE sID='$id'";
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
           $out[$id][]=$row;
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($out);

?>;</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I will check your code. here is a visual example of the result I try to achieve. http://oi68.tinypic.com/2j5h2me.jpg

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: yes, what I did is this according to your code and instructions. https://jsfiddle.net/c5eca23L/ I couldn't make it work. but if I am not mistaken about your instructions, your solution requires manual editing of javascript for every value to create js objects? in the example i have three tables, tables will be all same, it won't change. but values to be highlighted change regularly.

Comment: My solution is to set a js object with default values to be highlighted. In your code you're missing the defaultValue object, it is not defined. In my filled it was in the html part. You have to create a php variable with default values, convert it to json string and then output it as javascript object.

Comment: I edit my answer editing the php code with a more verbose solution with a DB query to compile a "$out" object to be print to javascript.

Comment: My code doesn't produce tr values like this <tr data-dbval=""> in this way. it this absolutely necessary?

Comment: It is not very safe and convenient to use content as selector, howevery you can: https://jsfiddle.net/r40ba286/ If you want to add data-dbval attribute you have to change your print_tableX function in the join of rows, it should be not very hard.

Comment: Thanks, Tobia for your time and help.